# How to update many records in a collection using firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this to try to update an user's username in posts:

```
let postsRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/');
postsRef.child('username').update({'username': "josh2"})
```

The problem is post is under a key, like so:

```
posts

  |
  ---- -MOFidfjdUSJFDJ
          |
          ----- username: josh (username)
          |
          ----- text: some text 1
  |
  ---- -MOFifdjfhd
          |
          ----- username: josh (username)
          |
          ----- text: some text 2
  ---- -MOjfdjsiJidJ
          |
          ----- username: marie (username)
          |
          ----- text: some text
```

I'd like to update any `posts` where username is `josh` to `josh2`. How can I do this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var postRef = firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild("username").equalTo("josh");
postRef.on('value', ((snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
    firebase.database().ref('posts').child(subChild.key).update({"username" :"josh2"});
  });
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

So here, you create a query to check if username is equal to josh, then you retrieve all this user's post, then using `key` property you can get the post key and update.